# calling gdb print from python script

Tags: gdb, gdb-python

I have a python gdb script that finds a pointer to some important value.

I want to call gdb print command to have this value assigned to value history for future references in other debug commands.

How to do it?

I know that I can define python function that will return this value - but I really want gdb command for backward compatibility with old gdb scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate python string and call gdb.execute

```
tmpVal = long(pointer)
tmpStr = "print (Xxxx *)0x{:x}".format(tmpVal)
gdb.execute(tmpStr)
```